# how to catch navigator.mediaDevices error?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, navigator

I have a video call feature on my angular app. now as soon as a person calls another person the callee or the caller are asked for microphone/camera access before starting a call. is there a way in typescript i can capture what error do i get if a user clicks on "block" for camera/micrphone access?

can anybody provide some useful link or piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... In a 'normal' way .. A one asking for permissions, could do in a `try...catch` block, and handle the `PermissionDeniedError`:

https://github.com/VovanSuper/Slider-teleprompter/blob/main/src/scripts/helpers/recorder.js#L72